# spring + aspectj, define an aspect @Around

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

i want to define an @Around aspect for a method of my @Entity

All my entities are in package data.entity

A define an aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Around("execution(* data.entity..*(..))")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("INTERCEPT: "+pjp.toLongString());
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

But never is intercepted... where is my error?

In spring xml i have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

       xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="data.dao, data.service" />

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="testAspect" class="spring.TestAspect" />

    ... datasource and other ...

</beans>
```

I try also

```
@Around("target(data.entity.MyEntity)")
```

and

```
@Around("target(data.entity..)")
```

but still not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you use spring-proxy-aop. This works only if the class is a spring manged bean, and the adviced method must be invoked from an other object.

Try to use real aspectJ instead of spring-proxy-aop.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started using AOP and below are the findings at my level

1. i am assuming you have necessary jar files, aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar and org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar present in your apps classpath.
2. The method aroundAdvice, as you have defined currently is perfect.
3. Could you remove the below line and try.

   <context:component-scan base-package="data.dao, data.service" />